# get request with XMLHttpRequest2 class returning undefined response

Tags: javascript

I'm following a guide for XMLHttpRequest2 on the html5 rocks website [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/). I am also learning how to create classes in JavaScript. Everything seems to be right, but when I test this code on jsfiddle it returns "error" twice from the if statement, and then response returns undefined. I suspect this is an issue with the class?

```
function Ajax(parameters) {
    this.type = parameters.type;
    this.url = parameters.url;
    this.format = parameters.format;
    this.send = parameters.send;
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

Ajax.prototype.initialize = function () {
    this.xhr.open(this.type, this.url, true);
    this.xhr.responseType = this.format;
    this.xhr.onload = this.process();
    this.xhr.send(this.send);
};

Ajax.prototype.process = function () {
    var self = this;
    if (self.xhr.readyState === 4 && self.xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(self.xhr.response));
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
};

var test = new Ajax({type:"GET", url:"http://ip.jsontest.com/", format:"text", send:""});

test.initialize();

console.log(test.process());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/FpskW/

You have two problems in your code:

1. In initialize, `this.xhr.onload` gains the value of the execution of the `proccess` function, not the function itself. `this.xhr.onload` needs a function, and with `()` in the end of `proccess` you are executing the code, instead of delegating.
2. If you do `this.xhr.onload = this.proccess`, you're passing the `proccess` function without a specific context. This way, when the XHR object executes the function, the function will have the context of the XHR object. The value of `this` when the `proccess` function gets executed, will be the XHR object, not your object. So, when the xhr object tries to execute `if (self.xhr.readyState === 4..` it will find that the XHR object doesn't have a property called xhr.

You can do something like this:

```
    Ajax.prototype.initialize = function () {
      this.xhr.open(this.type, this.url, true);
      this.xhr.responseType = this.format;

      // we capture the context of the Ajax object
      var self = this;

      // and we create a lambda that executes the 'proccess' function always with the context
      // of the Ajax object.
      this.xhr.onload = function() {
        self.process();
      }

      this.xhr.send(this.send);
    };
```

And that's all.

NOTE: In Javascript, we don't have classes, they're prototypes. :)

Comment: awesome!! thanks for explaining. do you know why it writes undefined to the console before processing the json?

Comment: Because in your last line you are calling the proccess function outside of all the ajax stuff. The return of the function in this case is "undefined" because you never returned anything there.